# Find corresponding column title for a specific value (based on 2 criteria)

Tags: excel

Sheet 1 contains some IDs and unique activity codes (CE, CI, EE, etc.) belong to that ID.

[image]

On sheet 2, I need to find the corresponding activity number (Activity 1, 2, or 3) for each activity code (CE, CI, EE, etc.) under that specific ID.

[image]

For example, sheet 2 row 2, Activity EE of ID 20001 is the 3rd Activity (Activity 3) based on the Sheet 1.

Ideally, the result should look like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what functions can I use to achieve this result? I need to avoid using VBA for this, and I don't want to create any extra concatenated "reference" column. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Side note - in the first screenshot, the ID numbers are left-aligned. Are they text or true numbers?

Comment: @BigBen I would say treat them as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one INDEX/MATCH to return the correct row and another to get the correct column from that row.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$F$1,MATCH(B2,INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$F,MATCH(A2&"",Sheet1!$A:$A,0),0),0))
```